# Lost SAS URI - is it recoverable?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We hired a guy to push a bunch of PST's to Azure (to be put into mailboxes) and he disappeared. We know he used a SAS URI and we know he did push the data up. We looked in storage explorer and dont see the data in any of our storage accounts. The guy deleted the original PST's so we cant just push the data back up.

as far as we know, he was using this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-network-upload-to-import-pst-files?view=o365-worldwide

1. can we find the SAS URI he used somewhere in azure?
2. can we explore this data somehow?

Any help is appreciated, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we find the SAS URI he used somewhere in azure?

Sadly no. Azure does not store the SAS URI anywhere.

> can we explore this data somehow?

You would need to know the storage account where the files were uploaded. Without that you will not be able to explore this data.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info! They have 2 storage accounts that we loaded into Azure Storage Explorer and we searched for "injestiondata" and got no results. I assume that using the link I posted above would use something from our storage account, right?

Comment: I believe `injestiondata` is the name of the blob container they just used as an example. What you would want to do is find out blobs with `pst` extension.

Comment: I dont find that in our storage accounts. I created a new SAS URI from our storage account and you can clearly see in the URI the org and storage account info. if you follow the guide above it appears to create a sas uri for a temp storage location from MS. Do you mind taking a peek to confirm this for me? thanks for all your help.

Comment: Let me read that document more carefully. I just glanced at it.

Comment: HEY! so yes - i am correct in what I thought. If you generate a SAS token from the Import wizard at protection.office.com it gives you a 30 day temp storage location from MS. The URI it spits out is from MS. Compare that to a SAS URI generated from a storage account, the URI contains the storage account name. Looks like my buddy has 30 days to track this guy down :) I will accept your answer but the real answer is to perform this process from a storage account you own and NOT let ms give you temp storage.